# Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' when i run many junit tests same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

when i run all junit tests with vscode i got some errors, but i don't get the error when i run just one test. i saw the same problem somebody posted within eclipse but i use vscode.

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getClassLoaderFor(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1444) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getClassLoaderFor(JmxMBeanServer.java:1324) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$6.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1365) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_161]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getClassLoaderFor(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1362) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:813) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might mean that you have one test that changes something in the state of your spring beans that affects following tests.
Try using [@DirtiesContext](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext) annotation on your tests